# Object.defineProperty without changing keys order

Tags: javascript

Whenever I change an existing property with Object.defineProperty the property goes to the top in the keys list. How to avoid it?

```
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'vendor', {
      enumerable: true,
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
      value: 'vendor'
    });

   for (var el in navigator) { console.log(el);}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example with input and expected output

Comment: property order in Objects is not (in general) guaranteed -

Comment: `navigator.vendor` doesn't exist. `Navigator.prototype.vendor` does, which you are shadowing.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects are not assures any key order, therefore, it is not reliable, it can be implemented in different browsers differently.

Use `Map`s for this task, which is preserving the insert order.

```js
const navigator = new Map();

navigator.set('vendor1', 'vendor');
navigator.set('vendor2', 'vendor');


for (var el of navigator) {
  console.log(el);
}
```